# Unlocked iPhone 4S w/no SIM Card-how to start up without contract

Tags: iphone, sim

I am using Android phone on Verizon now.
Last weekend, I got a present from friend "ARCCOS Golf" system which only works together with iPhone 4S or later.
I contacted ARCCOS support center and got the confirmation of "Unlocked iPhone 4S" can be used for Wi-Fi only (without contract) mode which I bought from Amazon.com and tried to start the iPhone 4S. It was stuck on "Insert SIM" but I do not have SIM Card nor I do not know how to insert it etc.
Please help me!!!
Thanks, S H Keum

Comment: Buy or borrow a SIM to get past that point.  It doesn't need to be in the phone once you get it setup.  You can't get past that point any other way.  The SIM you use doesn't even have to be activated.

Comment: Yeah, I just keep a couple of dummy SIM cards OFF various form factors around just for that purpose

Comment: Thank so much for your reply & comment. I just found out how to open the SIM holder on the phone and will find a SIM Card soon. Have a wonderful evening.

Answer (score 1):

Just a get a dummy SIM card off of eBay or maybe even from Verizon. Also look on the left side of the iPhone and you should see an oval indented with a hole in it. Stick a paperclip straight in and the tray holding the SIM card should pop out. If this isn't clear enough, I'm sure there is some YouTube videos on the subject.

Comment: Well understood. Will learn more details from the Youtube too. Thanks!